# Help with java calendar logic

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am working with the Java Calendar class to do the following:

1. Set a start date
2. Set an end date
3. Any date within that range is a "valid" date

I have this somewhat working, and somewhat not. Please see the code below:

```
    nowCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, nowCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + offset);
    int nowDay = nowCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

    Calendar futureCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    futureCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, nowDay + days);

    Date now = nowCalendar.getTime();
    Date endTime = futureCalendar.getTime();

    long now_ms = now.getTime();
    long endTime_ms = endTime.getTime();

    for (; now_ms < endTime_ms; now_ms += MILLIS_IN_DAY) {
        valid_days.addElement(new Date(now_ms));
        System.out.println("VALID DAY: " + new Date(now_ms));
    }
```

Basically, I set a "NOW" calendar and a "FUTURE" calendar, and then I compare the two calendars to find the valid days.  On my calendar, valid days will be shaded white and invalid days will be shaded gray. You will notice two variables:

```
    offset = three days after the current selected date
    days = the number of valid days from the current selected date
```

This works...EXCEPT when the current selected date is the last day of the month, or two days prior (three all together). I think that its the offset that is definitely screwing it up, but the logic works everywhere else.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fiddle with milliseconds. Clone the `nowCalendar`, add 1 day to it using `Calendar#add()` in a loop as long as it does not exceed `futureCalendar` and get the `Date` out of it using `Calendar#getTime()`.

```
Calendar clone = nowCalendar.clone();

while (!clone.after(futureCalendar)) {
    validDays.add(clone.getTime());
    clone.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

*(note that I improved `validDays` to be a `List` instead of the legacy `Vector`)*

Comment: BalusC- I did implement your solution (which is a lot cleaner, thank you), however I am still hitting my original issue. Before selecting any of my calendar dates, the NOW calendar is: 3/18/2011 and the FUTURE calendar is 3/31/2011. After selecting one of the last three days of the month, then the NOW calendar becomes 4/3/2011 and the FUTURE calendar becomes 4/2/2011.

Comment: Got it working - thanks. You were certainly right about not fiddling with milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use `add` instead of `set` in the first line, otherwise the month is not adjusted if you are at the month boundary:

```
nowCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, offset);
```

Comment: The problem is my application is for the BlackBerry, which contains only a subset of Java. Therefore, I have the set() method available to me but not the add() method...

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isInRange(Date d)
{
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(d);
   return cal.after(startCal) && cal.before(endCal);
}
```

Here the startCal is the calendar instance of start time and endCal is end time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

As soon as I set futureCalendar to be a clone of nowCalendar (plus the additional days), then it started working.  Thanks for everyone's suggestions!